# Javascript Animate Image Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make an image animate and make it larger. I have gotten it to change size but I am now trying to make it so none of the surrounding elements don't get moved around as well. I am using jQuery to do the animations and for some reason it wont increment the margin's every step. It only does it after it has finished. I thought I read the jQuery docs correctly. Here is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".image").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).animate({height: "176px", width: "250px"},
            {
            step: function(now, fx) {
                $(this).css("margin-left","-=0.076");
                $(this).css("margin-right","-=0.084");
                $(this).css("margin-bottom","-=0.152");
            }
        });
    });
    $(".image").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({height: "100px", width: "174px"},
            {
            step: function(now, fx) {
                $(this).css("margin-left","+=0.076");
                $(this).css("margin-right","+=0.084");
                $(this).css("margin-bottom","+=0.152");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It seems like this would actually be easier with CSS3...

Comment: OK, How would I go about doing that? I know CSS just not much of the more complex stuff like that.

Comment: I would check out: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/all/ and http://webexpedition18.com/articles/css-animations-resources-tutorials/

Comment: OK, CSS3 scale is much easier to use and gives me the exact effect I want! Thank you Connor! I would set it as the answer but you didn't make it one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try CSS3 animations:

```
img{
-webkit-transform:scale(0.6); /*Webkit: Scale down image to 0.6x original size*/
-moz-transform:scale(0.6); /*Mozilla scale version*/
-o-transform:scale(0.6); /*Opera scale version*/
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; /*Webkit: Animation duration*/
-moz-transition-duration: 0.5s; /*Mozilla duration version*/
-o-transition-duration: 0.5s; /*Opera duration version*/
}

.hovergallery img:hover{
-webkit-transform:scale(0.9); /*Webkit: Scale up image to most of the original size*/
-moz-transform:scale(0.9); /*Mozilla scale version*/
-o-transform:scale(0.9); /*Opera scale version*/
}
```

The above will scale the image on hover.

Comment: @legobear154 Is this like what you are thinking about using?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. Haven't been on in a while. Thank you very much again for the code!

Answer (score 1):

Without your html it's hard to tell but I think you're doing it the hard way. I suggest you do as much as possible with css and html and then worry about javascript. If you create a container with the same size as your image then you can just center the picture inside the container using the usual method to center stuff in css, but you animate it. I also would create a function to handle those animation just so its easier to use.

Check simple demo here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/XBmc9/) (cute kitten included)

```
$('img').animate({
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    top: 0,
    marginTop: '75px', // heigth / 2
    marginLeft: '100px' // width / 2
});
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid the box around the image. It is going to start out small and grow in size when hovered over and then shrink again when the mouse leaves the image.

Comment: @legobear154 Just remove the border on the wrapper div.